# How to support a "Save draft" to a wizard approach when the user takes a long time to complete a step?

Tags: usability, gui-design, buttons, user-expectation, workflow

I have simple user workflow, in which the User has to complete the process sequentially. But the step 2 might take a day or more to get completed.

In the Current UI, If user decides to complete the process later, they can click "save" to skip the process and they will be taken to summary page. User can save the whole process as draft. When the user returns back to edit, There will be no wizard approach. They can modify each step by individually selecting the process steps from the summary.

[image]

Is the approach is intuitive? Is there any alternate patterns to handle save draft in a wizard approach?

Comment: If step 2 is mandatory, you might want to consider showing step2 directly when user selects edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you swap summary and step 1, so basically one can check the all steps from single page itself, so they are prepared what info he or she needs to feel up. And you can take up the approach which you are following for the edit draft.

Actually I have come up across lot of places where I want to see first that what info or steps I am going to follow instead of following steps where I don't know where I am going to be step in next.

But again this also depends on what kind of data or steps you want your users to follow. But yeah in my general experience giving two different path one during creation and one during edit is always bit confusing to users.

Answer (score 0):

If your summary includes a progress bar, it will be easy for the user to visualize where they left and go back to this step quickly.

If the progress bar is present in each step, you might not even need the initial wizard.